# How do I show multiple items in Owl carousel?

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I'm using Owl carousel on my page. I need to use it in more than one section, but each section comes with different carousel design.

In my first carousel section I need to display two items at a time, but in the other section I need to display 4 items at a time.

In my js file I initialize the carousel like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel(
        {
            items: 2,
            slideBy: 2
        }
    );
});
```

But if I do this then I can only show 2 items in each section. Is there a way to somehow change the `items`, depending on the sections?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`owl-carousel` and `owl-theme` for default style. And you can write different classes for each carousels like this

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme first-slider"></div>
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme second-slider"></div>
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme third-slider"></div>
```

```
$(".first-slider").owlCarousel(
  //owl setting
);

$(".second-slider").owlCarousel(
  //owl setting
);

$(".third-slider").owlCarousel(
  //owl setting
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the all carousel calss different and assign them seprate for eaxample

```
<div class = "owl-carousel"> </div>
<div class = "owl-carousel-second"> </div>
<div class = "owl-carousel-third"> </div>
```

and jquery like
first:

```
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel(
        {
            items: 2,
            slideBy: 2
        }
    );
```

second:

```
$(".owl-carousel-second").owlCarousel(
        {
            items: 3,
            slideBy: 2
        }
    );
```

third:

```
$(".owl-carousel-third").owlCarousel(
        {
            items: 4,
            slideBy: 2
        }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But it will mess up the default owl carousel styles. So it's best to create a copy of the default owl css file and rename it. Also the .owl-carousel classes need to be renamed to .owl-carousel-second or whatever. As far as I can tell the js is not affected by this.

Comment: it looks like you are using the custom css so you can make another common class and assign it to all carousel